# GTP change connections: Cannot set LOC property

Tags: fpga

I have a PHY-CHIP with XAUI Interface connected to a A7-FPGA-CHIP(GTP).
My schematics say I should reconfigure the "polarity and order" of my incoming and outgoing xaui - GTP Pins.

Here an example:

- phy-xtx0_3N is wired to mgt216RX0P
- but I think it should be to mgt216RX3N

I tried to change my xdc file and I tried to connect the signals in my top lvl.

I get one critical warning like this:

```
[Vivado 12-1411] Cannot set LOC property of ports, Cannot set PACKAGE_PIN property of ports,  port a7_mgt216_rx_p_i[0] can not be placed on PACKAGE_PIN B11 because the PACKAGE_PIN is occupied by port a7_mgt216_rx_n_i[3] ["ts.xdc":25]
```

But  I get like 8 critical warnings of this :

```
[Vivado 12-1411] Cannot set LOC property of ports, Cannot set PACKAGE_PIN property of ports,  port a7_mgt216_rx_n_i[0] can not be placed on PACKAGE_PIN A11 because the PACKAGE_PIN is occupied by port a7_mgt216_rx_n_i[3] ["/home/constraints.xdc":26]
```

## Questions:

**What do you think:**

Is it possible to change it or is it bad luck if its not wired correctly on the pcb?
**Is there another XAUI example I could try?**
I don't think so right?
Its rather a very special topic right?
In best case I could fix the bad connection between GTP and XAUI right?

##### what may not work:

```
xaui< -> transceiver<-> **change order of signals** <-> phy
```

#### possible solution:

```
xaui <-> **change order of signals** <-> transceiver<-> phy
```

[image: phy-gtp-xaui]
lol i thought is easy but xaui is connected really strange to the transceiver. I thought it would just connect "directly" but there is something in between so I maybe cant change it that easy.

[image]
here you can see the entering connections from the phy  to the gtp.

Tx0 and Rx2 go to GTP Channel 1
and from there to the XAUI
I am really not sure if this will work xD
I counted them n/p swapped pairs: 3

[image: sorted connection]

## can I change this connection from GTP to XAUI Core easily?

[image: CAN I CHANGE THIS?]

What do you think about
TX/RX POLARITY it should switch some TX n/p and RX n/P of Channels.
Only problem would be mixed up lanes from XAUI to GTP^^

I need to check the Transceiver connections. How is a transceiver normally connected to incoming / outgoing data...

## Update:

change the *xci file now:

https://support.xilinx.com/s/article/57546?language=en_US

mgt_txdata_reord(2*16+15 downto 2*16) <= mgt_txdata(15 downto 0);

mgt_txdata_reord(3*16+15 downto 3*16) <= mgt_txdata(31 downto 16);

mgt_txdata_reord(1*16+15 downto 1*16) <= mgt_txdata(47 downto 32);

mgt_txdata_reord(0*16+15 downto 0*16) <= mgt_txdata(63 downto 48);

mgt_txcharisk_reord(2*2+1 downto 2*2) <= mgt_txcharisk(1 downto 0);

mgt_txcharisk_reord(3*2+1 downto 3*2) <= mgt_txcharisk(3 downto 2);

mgt_txcharisk_reord(1*2+1 downto 1*2) <= mgt_txcharisk(5 downto 4);

mgt_txcharisk_reord(0*2+1 downto 0*2) <= mgt_txcharisk(7 downto 6);

**What do you think about it?**

..

(I need also to change the polarity now of some lanes, with the config vector of the transceiver ..

maybe thats all

haha)

Answer (score 1):

Tranceivers are generally on dedicated pins so you cannot just remap them like that.

You might, maybe, be able to do your second option, but may need a register between the lut and the transceiver to meet timing if you need an inversion.

Comment: Ah the PHY is there as a chip. And it is connected to A7 FPGA. But it even sais in the schematics, that I should change some order xD So I wonder if its that easy

Comment: I should check the pin connection again. Sometimes its easier then it looks like. But if I really need to check the LUTs and the timing it might be complicated right?

Comment: I did of course mean transceivers are on dedicated pins.

Comment: yes .  I think I already understood :)  Someone right now told me, he had the same issue and had to do make a new board/pcb xD

Comment: TX/RX POLARITY may be could to change polarity.. what remains is the mixed up lanes that dont follow a order and cant be changed by the wizard. ... I should go deep into the xaui core design and check how transceiver send/ receive data normally.